# I want to change default product variation machine name?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I am working in Drupal Commerce kickstart. It's have default content types like hats,bags_cases,tops and all. I want to change the machine name also.Is it possible?

[image]

I am going to change structure->content types -> edit

[image]

But I can't change it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

if you want to edit the machine name of your content type name 'pages' then goto 'admin/structure/types/manage/page' --> click the "edit" button and update with the required value.

Same way you can do it for any content types.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Its possible in Drupal 7. But i am using Drupal commerce kickstart.

Comment: product variation types are not shown in the content type structure menu for commerce kickstart profiles

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the poster above didn't read your question properly and I wasted quite a bit of time thinking it could be done only I was looking in the wrong place or something.

Anyway, as far as I can see there is no drupal way to change the name of the machine name for a product variation. What I did to get around this was to 'hack' the database directly.

As always, backup you db first!

First of all I changed the variation type title to what it should be, in my case I was changing 'Drinks' to 'Charms'.

I did spend a lot of time trying to figure out which tables I needed to update but in the end the most efficient and error free way was to dump the whole database then open the .sql file into a text editor like Sublime text (I tried Coda but it was too sloooow as the file was 28mb) and do a search and replace, searching for 'drinks' and replacing it with 'charms' in my case.

Once done and saved to a new file I just re-imported it. Job done, so far no side effects. I'll post here if I find any. :-)